# Difference between various templates when creating web api project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a asp.net web api application using Visual Studio 2013. There are couple of ways using which you can create the project

1. `File > New > Project > Web > Visual Studio 2012 >  Asp.net MVC 4 web application > Web Api`
2. `File > New > Project > Visual C# > Asp.net web application > Web Api`
3. `File > New > Project > Web > Asp.net web application > Empty`
4. `File > New > Project > Web > Asp.net web application > Web Api`

Apart from option 3, all the other options add extra stuff Bootstrap, fonts (glyphicons), JQuery etc.

I just want to return data from the web api. Which is the right option to create the solution? Why do they add extra stuff to web api when it cannot return view?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want all of the scripts and style stuff you'll need to use the Empty Template.

> File > New Project > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application

[image: New Project Screenshot]

[image: Template Selection Screenshot]

Be warned: The template is very sparse. All you get are some empty folders and the *WebApiConfig.cs*.

Answer (score 0):

To choose option 4 for Web API ,by the way the Web API only can return data with XML or Json format , hopefully this information can help you , thanks

it is very easy sample for Web API code as following

public class a1Controller : ApiController
    {
        private gigadeEntities1 db = new gigadeEntities1();

```
    // GET: api/a1
    public IQueryable<a1> Geta1()
    {
        return db.a1;
    }

    // GET: api/a1/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(a1))]
    public IHttpActionResult Geta1(int id)
    {
        a1 a1 = db.a1.Find(id);
        if (a1 == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(a1);
    }
```

}

as below code
1.you can see picture 2 , the Web API has to be included by MVC structure , it can be returned the pure data (xml or json) by URL 
2.  picture 3 ,public class ValuesController : ApiController <-- using ApiController not Controller

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i know it can return either json or xml. But which option i need to select from the above stated option?

Comment: File > New > Project > Web > Asp.net web application > Web Api

Comment: Option 4 is the wrong one if you just want to return data and not have a UI.

Comment: Hi @OpenStack did you get the answer now , if not , I would try to tell you more ,hopefully I can help you to handle your problem, PS: I will add more information to Answer Content.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that #4 is badly designed. It's called web api, but it includes files that only apply to a web app (scripts, fonts, ...) that you don't need for an API server.

Seems that folks recommend going with #2 (empty). That does avoid including files you don't need, but it's very minimal. I have struggled to figure out how to add web api capabilities to it. There are many dependencies and source files that the web api template includes that may or may not be useful. I don't know which ones I should add and which ones I should ignore.

The two options seem to be:

1. Use Empty and add stuff you need. But, it's hard to know what one needs.
2. Use Web API and either remove stuff you don't need/use or just leave all the junk in there.

I spent the last two days on the path of using Empty, but it's not working. I'm about to start over using the Web API template.